# Element randomly not found while using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am running the script below to review the latest filings by public companies listed on the London Stock Exchange. I have encountered a weird bug. It works 3/4 of the times, however, It randomly fails to locate the elements that I am looking for. I am using `WebDriverWait` in each attempt to wait until element is loaded, locate any element. So I am not sure what else I can do to ensure that these elements are found. Any idea, How can I ensure 100% success rate in locating these elements?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

# click the cookies disclaimer
URL = f"https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news?tab=news-explorer&period=lastmonth&page=1"
driver.get(URL)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='ccc-notify-accept']"))
).click()

while True:
    try:
        URL = f"https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news?tab=news-explorer&period=lastmonth&page=1"
        driver.get(URL)
        # find the form dropdown parent and click it
        dropdown_path = '//*[@id="news-table-results"]/div[1]/form[1]'
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, dropdown_path))
        ).click()
        # search the dropdown for the largest viewing option (500 items) and select it
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Show 500 news')]")
            )
        ).find_element(By.XPATH, "..").click()
        # wait for the filing table to appear
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))
        print("Success")
    except:
        print("Failure")
        raise
```

The elements that are periodically not found are usually:

```
//*[@id="news-table-results"]/div[1]/form[1]
//*[contains(text(), 'Show 500 news')]
```

Comment: What element(s) here are randomly not found?

Comment: @Prophet I have just updated my question and mentioned the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're f-stringing a .. static url? Not sure why. Pulling 500 news takes more than 3 seconds you're waiting for that table to load. So either wait more, or just scrape the 20 news pages, until you're getting all 500 (that would be 25 pages).

Anyhow, the following code will pull all those news. I am breaking the while loop after the 5th page, but you can remove that condition if you want, or increase the number of pages, etc:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
big_df = pd.DataFrame()
counter = 1
while True:
    url = f'https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news?tab=news-explorer&period=lastmonth&page={counter}'
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ccc-notify-accept'))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        pass ## no cookies, so this pass is acceptable in this instance
    try:
        t.sleep(2)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'dropdownSize'))).click()
#         print('clicked the dropdown')
        t.sleep(10)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text() = " Show 500 news "]'))).click()
#         print('selected 500 news')
        t.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    try:
        table = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.full-width.table')))
        df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
        big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter > 5:
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
display(big_df)
```

The result is a 2.5K rows dataframe:

```
    Headline    Source  Date    Time    Price   Change %
0   Bushveld Minerals Limited - BMN - Total Voting Rights RNS 31 August 2022 08:35:04 5.90 -    RNS 31.08.22    08:35:04    5.90    -
1   Sampo PLC - 95BM - Tender Offer RNS 31 August 2022 08:34:57 - - RNS 31.08.22    08:34:57    -   -
2   Oil and Gas Development Company Ltd - OGDC - Material Information RNS 31 August 2022 08:20:50 5.00 -    RNS 31.08.22    08:20:50    5.00    -
3   Petra Diamonds Limited - PDL - Notification of FY22 Prelim Results Release PRN 31 August 2022 08:09:00 97.00 -  PRN 31.08.22    08:09:00    97.00   -
4   F&C Investment Trust PLC - FCIT - Transaction in Own Shares RNS 31 August 2022 08:08:02 895.00 -0.33%   RNS 31.08.22    08:08:02    895.00  -0.33%
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2495    RM PLC - RM. - RM plc: Holiding(s) in Company EQS 30 August 2022 08:14:22 46.50 -   EQS 30.08.22    08:14:22    46.50   -
2496    NatWest Group plc - NWG - Share consolidation and total voting rights RNS 30 August 2022 08:10:44 249.05 0.02%  RNS 30.08.22    08:10:44    249.05  0.02%
2497    Harvest Minerals Limited - HMI - Result of AGM RNS 30 August 2022 08:06:30 11.40 -1.30% RNS 30.08.22    08:06:30    11.40   -1.30%
2498    Speedy Hire PLC - SDY - Director Declaration RNS 30 August 2022 08:00:04 41.00 -    RNS 30.08.22    08:00:04    41.00   -
2499    X5 Retail Group N.V. - FIVE - X5 upgrades Paket by X5 subscription service RNS 30 August 2022 08:00:04 0.53 -   RNS 30.08.22    08:00:04    0.53    -
2500 rows × 6 columns
```

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. My question specifically mentions that I would like to make 500 filing rows visible per page and the failure occurs while trying to achieve this. Your answer assumes just 20 filing rows per page, which is not the way I want to run this script.

Comment: If we are using `WebDriverWait` then it would be better to use it, rather then `time.sleep()`. For more information visit [Elegant Method for Sleeping with Selenium Webscraper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238270/elegant-method-for-sleeping-with-selenium-webscraper)

Comment: @Xitiz you can see I am using explicit Waits. However, that element already exists in page (the table with that class), so I would need to combine implicit with explicit waits, and that's not reccomended (Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. ): https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/ So I decided to simply use time.sleep(), to avoid such issues.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire thanks for updating your answer. Why do you use time.sleep(), when we already have the WebDriverWait? I assume that the point of WebDriverWait  is to specifically avoid waiting for a set amount of time. No, it was not me who downvoted :)

Comment: @AleisterCrowley you're welcome. I was only trying to clarify the eventual inconsistencies in your code (that f-string for example?), and also to avoid an eventual X-Y problem: your ultimate goal is to get those news, and the easiest, most straightforward way (which also avoids eventual errors occurring from selenium not being able to reliably click on that non-standard dropdown list, etc) would be to avoid any clicks, and just get the 20-per-page tables, one by one. Nonetheless, the solution above works for the 500 news table. I'm using time.sleep() to avoid combining implicit/explicit waits.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire why would you use an implicit wait in here? Aren't the explicit waits ( the WebDriverWait()) enough for the element to be clickable? I just want to understand what and why was wrong with my original code and how exactly your code solves this.

Comment: @AleisterCrowley when page initially loads, we have a 20-news table with class `full-width table`. After we click on the dropdown and select the 500 news option, that table will load 500 news via an XHR call (so page itself won't reload), but it will have the same class (which we use to select it). Hence, after clicking the 500 news and telling selenium to wait until .., it will not wait, but instead select the 20-news table, and will eventually throw an error as well. To avoid that, we would need an implicit wait: as we already use explicit waits, combining those would not be advised.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire thanks, that's clear. Many thanks for taking the time to explain this thoroughly.

Comment: Using a combination of sleep and WebDriverWait defeats the benefits of WebDriverWait. If the page reloads, Selenium already blocks progress until the page is loaded so a sleep isn't needed. If the page isn't reloading, a better practice would be to use WebDriverWait and wait for `staleness_of` an element that is going to be reloaded then do your usual WebDriverWait for visible, clickable, etc.

Comment: Also, declare `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)` at the top of the script and then use `wait.until()` throughout the script. There's no need to reinstantiate the same wait more than once.

Comment: @JeffC, I appreciate your criticism. In this particular case, I stand by my solution though. You're welcome to try it out without using hard sleep, and you'll see why.